# How to assign webkit styles to an element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, webkit

I am trying to assign webkit styles to an element but can not get it to work.
This is what I need to assign:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
```

This is what I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("EL").style.webkitBoxShadowInset = '0px 0px 0px 10px #f00';
document.getElementById("EL").style.mozBoxShadowInset = '0px 0px 0px 10px #f00';
document.getElementById("EL").style.boxShadowInset = '0px 0px 0px 10px #f00';
```

Comment: The rules name aren't valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("EL").style.WebkitBoxShadow = 'inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00';
document.getElementById("EL").style.MozBoxShadow = 'inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00';
document.getElementById("EL").style.boxShadow = 'inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00';
```

note the capitalization of Webkit* and Moz* and the location of the word inset

Comment: I was about to expand the answer to explain what you did wrong, do you need that explanation?

Answer (score 1):

You can optimise the result :

```
var el = document.getElementById("EL"),
    bS = 'inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00';

el.style.WebkitBoxShadow = el.style.MozBoxShadow = el.style.boxShadow = bS;
```